# Detect changes on existing ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am writing an ActiveRecord extension that needs to know when an association is modified. I know that generally I can use the :after_add and :after_remove callbacks but what if the association was already declared?

Comment: Can you use [Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html)?  Perhaps a sample of code to show what is already being done right now might help...

Answer (score 5):

You could simply overwrite the setter for the association. That would also give you more freedom to find out about the changes, e.g. have the assoc object before and after the change E.g.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  def articles= new_array
    old_array = self.articles
    super new_array
    # here you also could compare both arrays to find out about what changed
    # e.g. old_array - new_array would yield articles which have been removed
    #   or new_array - old_array would give you the articles added 
  end
end
```

This also works with mass-assignment.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, you can use `after_add` and `after_remove` callbacks. Additionally set `after_commit` filter for association models and notify "parent" about change.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :after_add => :read, :after_remove => :read     

  def read(article)
    # ;-)
  end
end 

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_commit { user.read(self) }
end
```

Comment: I am writing an extension to ActiveRecord, so assume that the has_many :articles has already been declared. Is there a way to add the :after_add and :after_remove callbacks after the fact?

Comment: @VenkatD. You can do something like `User.after_add_for_articles = [:read]`

Comment: Thanks sheerun, is this behavior documented somewhere? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @VenkatD. You can find the [undocumented behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb#L62) in `ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder`'s `CollectionAssociation` class. It creates a getter and setter called `ModelClass::[callback name]_for_[association name]`.